# How to separate text depending text in line

Tags: notepad++

I have like 200 lines that I want to divide into 20. I don't know how to explain.

For example:

```
test:test | US
testt2:testsdgad | CZ
hksfdg:gsdsd | UK
```

I want to separate the lines that have `| UK` , `| US` and `| CZ` on different rows. I mean like convert it to this format:

```
test:test | US
test:test | US
test:test | US
test:test | CZ
test:test | CZ
test:test | UK
test:test | UK
test:test | UK
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is this really the output you want from that input? If not, please edit your question.

Comment: yes it is what i want

Comment: Sorry. Then I cannot deduce the transformation from input to output. cya.

Comment: Please provide a better description and/or more complete example. Voting to close your question in its current form.

Comment: Do you mean sorting by last two letters?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what OS you're using.  This works for Linux, and maybe for Windows too, if you have  awk, [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm), nawk or mawk.

First generate a data file.  You already have one, so you can skip this step.

```
for n in {1..66}; do for c in US CZ UK; do echo "test$n:test$n | $c" >> data.in; done; done
```

Then pipe it into `awk` (or `gawk` etc.) for sorting and printing.

```
cat data.in | awk -- '{a[$3] = a[$3] $0 "\n"}; END{print a["US"] a["CZ"] a["UK"]}' > data.out
```

The output looks like this:

```
...
test65:test65 | US
test66:test66 | US
test1:test1 | CZ
test2:test2 | CZ
...
```